# TCP sockets: Can the transport layer access the network layer header?

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp

In my class, we learned that a TCP socket is uniquely identified by the 4-tuple consisting of source IP, destination IP, source port, and destination port.

Now suppose I have a web server running on port 80. It has 2 TCP sockets established to two clients that have different IP addresses but somehow both use the same source port, say 12345.

We also learned in class that the transport layer header adds only the source/destination ports whereas the network layer adds the source/destination IP addresses.

Now suppose the web server receives two packets, one from each client. As mentioned, the source port, destination port, destination IP addresses are the same in these packets, so the only difference is the source IP address.

However, if demultiplexing is done by the transport layer, how can the source IP address be used to move the packet to the right socket? After all, the source IP address is only part of the network header and, as far as I understand, that header is already stripped off before the packet is passed from the network layer up to the transport layer on the receiving side.

Comment: What makes you think the network header is stripped off? The IP (network) header precedes the TCP (transport) header in the packet data. The packet bytes don't gets shifted around as the packet is passed between the layers.  Just different layers look at the different sections of the packet as needed until it is routed to the proper destination socket, which then stores the final payload bytes to its receive buffer, waiting for the owning app to read from that buffer.

Comment: I see, that makes sense!